# How to handle camel-quickfix CannotSendException?

Tags: apache-camel, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, camel-quickfix

I am using [QuickFix/J](https://www.quickfixj.org/) 1.6.4 in a [camel-quickfix component](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-quickfix). Sometimes, I get the **CannotSendException** and it is not clear, what the exception cause is. I looked at the [code](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-quickfix/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/quickfixj/QuickfixjProducer.java), but there it seems that this exception is thrown, when the message could not be send - regardless of the reason.

So how do I have to handle this exception? Do I have to implement a retry mechanism, or does the engine handle this for me? If the engine does, how can I verify, that the message is sent afterwards?

Exception Stacktrace (I replaced the FIX message with *** because I cannot publish it):

```
org.apache.camel.component.quickfixj.CannotSendException: Cannot send FIX message: ***
at org.apache.camel.component.quickfixj.QuickfixjProducer.sendMessage(QuickfixjProducer.java:75)
at org.apache.camel.component.quickfixj.QuickfixjProducer.process(QuickfixjProducer.java:47)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:101)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:220)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:183)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:33)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:136)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:114)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:555)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:515)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:485)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:243)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1164)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:634)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
```

Comment: Please add the exception trace to your question.

Comment: I added the exception stacktrace to my question @TT. , I cannot publish the FIX message itself, but I hope the stacktrace can help. I do not expect the exception cause in the FIX message anyway.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't say much. Other messages get through fine?

Comment: Yes, that's the weird one here. The heartbeats go through too.

Comment: Is there a logging interceptor for the camel-quickfix component? Maybe I get more information then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [nabble on this topic](https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Handling-unsuccessful-Session-send-in-Quickfix-component-td5680836.html) and in [camel-quickfix](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quickfix-component.html) versions before Camel 2.10.0 it was probably not possible to ensure that a FIX message was sent. This has been changed with the [CAMEL-5247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5247) patch and the **CannotSendException** has been added. So it is now possible to [configure the sending of FIX messages as a synchronous write](https://quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/configuration.html) with *SocketSynchronousWrites*, even if it is not recommended for performance reasons.

> Write messages synchronously. This is not generally recommended as it may result in performance degradation. The MINA communication layer is asynchronous by design, but this option will override that behavior if needed.

So now you can also get info about failed sending of FIX messages, even if you do not use SocketSynchronousWrites. **The error handling must then be implemented in the application**.