# How to configure QuickFix/J for daily sessions from Monday to Friday?

Tags: apache-camel, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, camel-quickfix

I am using [QuickFix/J](http://quickfixengine.org/) 1.6.4 in [camel-quickfix](https://camel.apache.org/staging/components/latest/quickfix-component.html) component. I would like to have the following session schedule: **Daily sessions from Monday to Friday from 6am to 8pm**. So the session should start on Monday 6am and stop at Monday 8pm and this for all weekdays. On Saturday and Sunday there sould not be any Session Logon.

Is there a simple configuration I missed for that really common use case?
I have seen some workarounds with cron jobs etc. but is there a more elegant way?

I also tried to use a quickfix configuration for every weekday and check which one to use, but I ended up in a [CannotSendException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362805/how-to-handle-camel-quickfix-cannotsendexception) an I think the Instances for that one session are in conflict.

Comment: In 2.x there's a configuration element for `Weekdays`. Not in versions before 2.x, so you're left to your own devices to implement that.

Comment: Hey @TT., thanks for the hint to [QuickFix/J Version 2.x configuration](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.0.0/usage/configuration.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I have asked for an elegant solution and not after a workaround, the answer is then the **upgrade to a newer [Camel version](https://camel.apache.org/categories/Releases/)**. As @TT had written in his comment, [QuickFix/J](https://quickfixj.org/) version 2.0.0 and newer have the [**Weekdays configuration**](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html#Session).

> For daily sessions that are active on specific days of the week.
> Use in combination with StartTime and EndTime.
> Incompatible with StartDay and EndDay.
> If StartTime is before EndTime then the day corresponds to the StartTime.

> ---

> Comma-delimited list of days of the week in the default locale (e.g. "Sun,Mon,Tue", "Dimanche,Lundi,Mardi" etc.)

QuickFix/J version 2.0.0 and newer are included in camel-quickfix **since Camel 2.21.0**. You can see this for example in the [MVNRepository of camel-quickfix](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-quickfix/2.21.0).