# How to configure QuickFIX/N to support daily session from Monday to Friday only

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am using [QuickFix/n](https://new.quickfixn.org/n/) v1.10.0 to establish daily sessions for weekdays only. As answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57406970/8483576) question, I tried using `Weekdays` configuration key but it doesn't seem to be supported in this version of the library, which is currently the latest one.

[Documentation](https://new.quickfixn.org/n/documentation/#item-quickfix-settings-4) describes the configuration for sessions lasting more than a day, but there are no words about this issue.

Is there an easy configuration for this functionality?

Comment: Quickfixj supports it, but quickfixn doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a feature in QF/n right now.

(I am lead maintainer of QF/n, so you can trust this answer.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestions on how should I approach to building a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately no, other than using a Windows service to shut your app down on friday and restart it on monday.  This is definitely something overdue for addition to QF/n.

Comment: Any plans for adding it in the near future?